# using brackets in hiera yaml

Tags: yaml, puppet, hiera

I have some hiera yaml that looks like this:

```
   vars:
      psuName:  xxxxx
      liveCustomers: 100
      notes: some notes here (more info in backets)
      uplink: uplink01
```

The yaml is autogenerated by a script and it is basically used to help build icinga2 config. The problem I have is that the output looks like this in the config file:

```
  vars.psuName = "xxxxx"
  vars.liveCustomers = 100
  vars.notes = some notes here ("more info in backets")
  vars.uplink = "uplink01"
```

So puppet has put quotes around most fields which is what I want, but on the notes field it has put quotes only around the text inside the bracket, I want it to look like this:

```
  vars.notes = "some notes here (more info in backets)"
```

I have tried changing the hiera yaml to look like this:

```
  notes: "some notes here (more info in backets)"
```

but it makes no difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are having type conversion and string escape issues here. When Puppet is loading in the YAML, it is casting the values to Ruby strings when the YAML is loaded and then output as Puppet strings to the Icinga2 config when Puppet is applied. Your script generating the Hiera YAML needs to be fixed to output proper values according to type. Additionally, your change to the Hiera YAML would fix your problem as stated, so there is a key difference between your question and actual data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MattSchuchard
I adjusted the hiera YAML to have the string inside double quotes and also tried single quotes but it gave the same output.
Then I tried replacing the brackets so the yaml looked like this:
notes: some notes here - more info no longer in brackets
but this time the output had quotes around everything after the -
what finally worked in the end but is far from ideal is
notes: some notes here-more info no longer in brackets
(basically I removed the spaces around the -)

Comment: Yeah a ` - ` without type context would probably cause issues within the YAML. I recommend modifying the script to handle it if it is not naturally handled with a language lib like `psych` (Ruby) or `ruamel.yaml` (Python).